How to create two types of new sections (error)
I need to create two types of sections.
The first section (sectionc) works without errors.
The second (sectionlcc) is similar to the first, but without \MakeUppercase. It does not work. Error in line: {\filcenter #1}.
MWE:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\makeatletter
%----------------------------------------
\newcounter{sectionc}
\titleclass{\sectionc}{straight}[\part]
\titleformat{\sectionc}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{}
{0pt}
{\filcenter \MakeUppercase{#1}}
[]
%
\titlespacing*{\sectionc}{0pt}{14pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{14pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
%
\titlecontents{sectionc}
[0em]
{\normalfont}
{\MakeUppercase}
{}
{\nolinebreak\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
[]
\def\toclevel@sectionc{0} % ToC level sectionc = chapter
%----------------------------------------
\newcounter{sectionlcc}
\titleclass{\sectionlcc}{straight}[\part]
\titleformat{sectionlcc}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{}
{0pt}
{\filcenter #1}
[]
%
\titlespacing*{\sectionlcc}{0pt}{14pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{14pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
%
\titlecontents{sectionlcc}
[0em]
{\normalfont}
{}
{}
{\nolinebreak\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
[]
\def\toclevel@sectionlcc{1} % ToC level sectionlcc = section
%----------------------------------------
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\sectionc{no number + uppercase + bold + center + no parindent}

no number + uppercase + bold + center + no parindent

\sectionlcc{no number + bold + center + no parindent}

no number + bold + center + no parindent

\end{document}


You have
\titleformat{\sectionc}[block]

with a \ 
and
\titleformat{sectionlcc}[block]

with no \ 
Changing that to
\titleformat{\sectionlcc}[block]

it runs without error.

\titleformat and \titlespacing require the command name with the backslash in the first argument, whereas \titlecontents wants the command name without the backslash.
If you aren't going to use \section, you can simplify the code a lot, however.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\filcenter}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}
  {14pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
  {14pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlecontents{section}
  [0em]
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {}
  {\nolinebreak\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\NewDocumentCommand{\sectionc}{O{#2}m}{%
  \section[\MakeUppercase{#1}]{\MakeUppercase{#2}}%
}
\NewCommandCopy{\sectionlcc}{\section}

\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\sectionc[With short title]{A section title which is very long and we want it shorter in the toc}

\sectionc{no number + uppercase + bold + center + no parindent}

no number + uppercase + bold + center + no parindent

\sectionlcc[Shorter]{no number + bold + center + no parindent}

\sectionlcc{no number + bold + center + no parindent}

no number + bold + center + no parindent

\end{document}


